# LNK2019 with Templates

Tags: c++, templates

Why I still got link error LNK2019 even though I defined and implemented template in the same file? 
Here is my code:

```
#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H_
#define _LINKEDLIST_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node* pNext;
    };
    node* pHead;
    node* pTail;
    int count;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    bool isEmpty();
    int getLength();
    bool insert(int position, T value);
    bool remove(int position);
    bool addHead(T value);
    bool addTail(T value);
    bool removeHead();
    bool removeTail();
    void clear();
    T getEntry(int position);
    void setEntry(int position, T value);
};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList();

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList();

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty();

template <class T>
int LinkedList<T>::getLength();

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::insert(int position, T value);

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::remove(int position);

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::addHead(T value);

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::addTail(T value);

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::removeHead();

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::removeTail();

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear();

template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::getEntry(int position);

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::setEntry(int position, T value);

#endif
```

And how to split it into two file? I searched and find some methods like include both `.h` and `.cpp` in main file or include `.cpp` in `.h` file but it didn't work.

Comment: Where did you implement the template here ?

Comment: [OT]: Avoid `using namespace` in header files.

Comment: `template <class T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList();` is **not** a definition/implementation.

Comment: but without using namespace how can I use cin or cout?

Comment: _"but without using namespace ..."_ Just say `std::cout` `std::cin` etc.

Comment: I tried not using "using namespace" but it didn't work

Comment: @H.L.Alumnus _"but it didn't work"_, yes because you have to specify it explicitly then, as I mentioned.

Comment: thanks, I wrote the constructor and destructor and it worked, but is there any way to split it into 2 file .cpp and .h?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the above question, as written in some comments, is that you were not defining but just declaring the template:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
 ...
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    ...
};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(); // Not a definition
```

and regarding your question *"can I split it into cpp and h files?"* there's another different question which addresses the issue in depth: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)